# Schengen tourist visa bank statement for an Indian student

Tags: indian-citizens, tourist-visas, czech-republic

I'm a senior undergrad, planning on a winter break trip to the Czech republic. My father's sponsoring my trip, but he is self employed and the balance in each of his accounts fluctuate highly between INR 2000 to INR 2 lakh because of constant transactions. When I apply, his bank account will show requisite funds though. So will the low amount at times be a problem for the visa application?

Comment: `I'm a senior undergrad, planning on a winter break trip to the Czech republic.` - you are immediately a high risk applicant. I would make sure I have evidence of ties to your homeland as you are prime candidate for immigration (legal or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

The Schengen visa officials will want to gauge your **credibility and lifestyle** and the **source of your funds**. So they will look at your bank accounts and those of your father.

- Regarding the **source of funds**, the the important thing is that the money was legally earned and that it is yours to spend on tourism. If the money looks like a credit, or if it is unclear where it came from, they might think that you plan to repay it by working illegally in Europe. It should be an amount that your father can reasonably afford.
- Regarding the **lifestyle**, your own bank account account should show stable deposits from your father for your monthly cost of living and the deposits for the trip.

Sure, a more steady income would be better. But not everybody has a steady income, and the visa officials realize that. Make sure that the rest of your application looks good.